# rails has_many :through NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I have the following setup

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 

has_many :category_products
has_many :products, through: :category_products

end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :category_products
has_many :categories, through: :category_products

end

class CategoryProducts < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :product
end
```

In rails console I try allocate category_ids using the following command
p.category_ids = [1,2]  (where p = Product.first) I get

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Product::CategoryProduct
```

any advice?

thanks

Comment: turns out, rails doesn't like a 'multi' name for the joining model, created a new model called categorization and all works 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just make a typo. try this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :categories_products
  has_many :products, through: :categories_products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories_products
  has_many :categories, through: :categories_products
end

class CategoriesProduct < ActiveRecord::Base # singular association model define
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product
end
```

careful about the association name.

**model**: `categories_product`(no **s**), and it's **table** `categories_products`

Answer (score 0):

turns out, rails doesn't like a 'multi' name for the joining model, created a new model called categorization and all works 100%